# Como tornar a cor do cabeçalho de PanelGrid Dinâmico no Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

Preciso dinamizar a cor de exibição da testeira do PanelGrid presente no Primefaces 5.1

Answer (score 1):

Nativamente o PrimeFaces nao tem uma propriedade que permita alterar o estilo do cabeçalho, mas voce pode criar seu proprio CSS customizando alterando a classe `ui-widget-panelheader`, pois ela é a responsavel por ele.